# Android Unit Testing: Bundle/Parcelable

Tags: android, unit-testing, bundle, parcelable

How do you unit test Parcelable?  I created a Parcelable class, and wrote this unit test

```
TestClass test = new TestClass();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("test", test);

TestClass testAfter = bundle.getParcelable("test");
assertEquals(testAfter.getStuff(), event1.getStuff());
```

I purposely try to fail the test by returning null in the `createFromParcel()`, but it seems to succeed. It looks like it doesn't get parceled until it's needed. How do I force the Bundle to..bundle?

Comment: If either of our anwers as a solution to your problem, please mark them as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I've found this link showing how you can unit test a parcelable object:
http://stuffikeepforgettinghowtodo.blogspot.nl/2009/02/unit-test-your-custom-parcelable.html

You can actually skip the `Bundle` if you don't really need to include it like zorch did his suggestion. You would then get something like this:

```
public void testTestClassParcelable(){
    TestClass test = new TestClass();

    // Obtain a Parcel object and write the parcelable object to it:
    Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
    test.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);

    // After you're done with writing, you need to reset the parcel for reading:
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);

    // Reconstruct object from parcel and asserts:
    TestClass createdFromParcel = TestClass.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
    assertEquals(test, createdFromParcel);
}
```

Comment: `parcel.setDataPosition(0);` was the secret. Thanks

Comment: Works for me too.  Thanks!.

Comment: Has no chance to work! You will always get ```BadParcelableException```.

Comment: @ddmytrenko BadParcelableException occurs when the object itself is parceled incorrectly. e.g. When your read and write objects are not in the same order

Comment: actually it is here : https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests?hl=en#java

Answer (score 19):

You can do it by this way:

```
//Create parcelable object and put to Bundle
    Question q = new Question(questionId, surveyServerId, title, type, answers);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("someTag", q);

//Save bundle to parcel
    Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
    b.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);

//Extract bundle from parcel
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);
    Bundle b2 = parcel.readBundle();
    b2.setClassLoader(Question.class.getClassLoader());
    Question q2 = b2.getParcelable("someTag");

//Check that objects are not same and test that objects are equal
    assertFalse("Bundle is the same", b2 == b);
    assertFalse("Question is the same", q2 == q);
    assertTrue("Questions aren't equal", q2.equals(q));
```

Comment: Have you tried with this kind of assertion: `Assert.assertTrue(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(q2, q));` ? 
I ask because in case you have a `List<obj> = new ArrayList<obj>` as a field in your `Question.java` data model then the code you wrote it doesn't work. If you have `ArrayList<obj> = new ArrayList<obj>` it works. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

Since this question and answers helped me several years down the line, I thought I'd add my own suggestion, which would be to `assert` that the `dataPosition()` at the end of the read was the same as at the end of the write. Building on [Xilconic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14548276/9195194):

```
@Test
public void testTestClassParcelable(){
    TestClass test = new TestClass();

    // Obtain a Parcel object and write the parcelable object to it:
    Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
    test.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);

    //>>>>> Record dataPosition
    int eop = parcel.dataPosition();

    // After you're done with writing, you need to reset the parcel for reading:
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);

    // Reconstruct object from parcel and asserts:
    TestClass createdFromParcel = TestClass.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
    assertEquals(test, createdFromParcel);

    //>>>>> Verify dataPosition
    assertEquals(eop, parcel.dataPosition());
}
```

---

**Background:** This came to me after spending an (embarrassing) amount of time debugging a bad `Parcelable`. In my case, `writeToParcel` was writing a duplicate field from one object within a moderately complex object graph. Therefore **subsequent** objects were read incorrectly, giving misleading exceptions, and no errors on tests with the specific misbehaving object.

It was a pain to track down, and then I realized checking `dataPosition` would have pinpointed the problem faster since I have tests on inner objects as well as the main container.

---

**Kotlin:** Since I am working in Kotlin, a little lambda and reifying magic:

```
class ParcelWrap<T>(val value: T)

val <T> T.parcel: ParcelWrap<T> get() = ParcelWrap(this)

inline fun <reified T: Parcelable> ParcelWrap<T>.test(
        flags: Int = 0,
        classLoader: ClassLoader = T::class.java.classLoader,
        checks: (T) -> Unit
): T {
    // Create the parcel
    val parcel: Parcel = Parcel.obtain()
    parcel.writeParcelable(this.value, flags)

    // Record dataPosition
    val eop = parcel.dataPosition()

    // Reset the parcel
    parcel.setDataPosition(0)

    // Read from the parcel
    val newObject = parcel.readParcelable<T>(classLoader)

    // Perform the checks provided in the lambda
    checks(newObject)

    // Verify dataPosition
    assertEquals("writeToParcel wrote too much data or read didn't finish reading", eop, parcel.dataPosition())
    return newObject
}
```

I can now test very easily along these lines, if there is a complete and reliable `equals()`:

```
testObject.parcel.test { assertEquals(testObject, it) }
```

Note the `.parcel.test` avoids having to re-specify generic type parameter using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39598190/9195194).

Or, for more complex assertions:

```
testObject.parcel.test {
    assertEquals(123, it.id)
    assertEquals("dewey", it.name)
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a parcel helper class to convert an object to/from parcel.

See this gist: https://gist.github.com/scallacs/f749a7385bcf75829a98d7b651efd02e

Usage is very simple:

```
Model model = new Model("HelloWorld");
// Create an object from the parcel model
Model createdFromParcel = ParcelTestHelper.createFromParcel(model, model.CREATOR);

// Do your assertions...
assertEquals(model.value, createdFromParcel.value);
```

The implementation:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class ParcelTestHelper {

    public static String DEFAULT_CREATOR_FIELD = "CREATOR";

    public static <T extends Parcelable> T createFromParcel(T input, Parcelable.Creator<T> creator) {
        Parcel parcel = toParcel(input);
        return fromParcel(parcel, creator);
    }

    public static <T extends Parcelable> T createFromParcel(T input) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        return createFromParcel(input, getCreator(input));
    }

    public static <T extends Parcelable> Parcel toParcel(T input) {
        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        input.writeToParcel(parcel, input.describeContents());
        parcel.setDataPosition(0);
        return parcel;
    }

    public static <T> Parcelable.Creator<T> getCreator(T input) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        return getCreator(input, DEFAULT_CREATOR_FIELD);
    }

    public static <T> Parcelable.Creator<T> getCreator(T input, String field) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Object creator = input.getClass().getField(field).get(input);
        if (!(creator instanceof Parcelable.Creator)) {
            throw new InternalError("Should have field " + field + " instance of Parcelable.Creator");
        }
        return (Parcelable.Creator<T>) creator;
    }

    public static <T extends Parcelable> T fromParcel(Parcel parcel, Parcelable.Creator<T> creator) {
        return creator.createFromParcel(parcel);
    }
}
```