# How do I constrain a Kotlin extension function parameter to be the same as the extended type?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to write an extension method on a generic type T, where the matched type constrains a method parameter.

I want this to compile:

```
"Hello".thing("world")
```

But not this, as 42 is not a String:

```
"Hello".thing(42)
```

This definition doesn’t work, because T is satisfied by `Any`

```
fun <T> T.thing(p: T) {}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned by [@Alexander Udalov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39596613/155213) it's not possible to do directly but there's a workaround where you define the extension method on another type like so:

```
data class Wrapper<T>(val value: T)

val <T> T.ext: Wrapper<T> get() = Wrapper(this)

fun <T> Wrapper<T>.thing(p: T) {
    println("value = $value, param = $p")
}
```

With the above the following compiles:

```
"abc".ext.thing("A")
```

but the next fails

```
"abc".ext.thing(2)
```

with:

```
Kotlin: Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter T in fun <T> Wrapper<T>.thing(p: T): Unit
None of the following substitutions
receiver: Wrapper<String>  arguments: (String)
receiver: Wrapper<Int>  arguments: (Int)
can be applied to
receiver: Wrapper<String>  arguments: (Int)
```

As suggested by @hotkey it seems that it should be possible to avoid the need for explicit `Wrapper` type with the following extension property:

```
val <T> T.thing: (T) -> Any? get() = { println("extension body") }
```

And then use it as `"abc".thing("A")` but **it also fails**. Surprisingly the following does compile `"abc".thing.invoke("A")`

Comment: It would be possible to define an extension property and add `invoke()` function to `Wrapper` to make this workaround syntactically identical to function call, but there seems to be a bug in the compiler which prevents me from doing so.

Comment: Funny thing is that even `("abc".foo)("abc")` works. :D

Comment: I think given the bug, this is going to be accepted, but thanks @hotkey for the work

Comment: In practice`Wrapper` doesn't even need to capture a parameter, just be returned and have `.get()` defined.

Comment: This no longer works in Kotlin 1.4. It will simply compile.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, this is not possible in Kotlin 1.0. There are several issues in the tracker ([first](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13198), [second](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13138)) about a similar use case, and the solution proposed in the first one is likely going to help here in the future as well.

Answer (score 5):

Improving @miensol's workaround and making it visually identical to function call:

```
val <T> T.foo: (T) -> SomeType get() = { other -> ... }
```

This is an extension property that provides a lambda, which can be immediately called with an argument of the same type `T` like this:

```
"abc".foo(1) // Fail
"abc".foo("def") // OK
```

---

Unfortunately, there **[seems to be a bug in the compiler](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13965)** which prevents you from writing `"abc".thing("abc")`, but either of `"abc".thing.invoke("abc")` and `("abc".thing)("abc)` work well and filter out calls with non-strings.