# Generic extensions of KProperty1 in Kotlin

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I have the following code:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty1


infix fun <T, R> KProperty1<T, R>.eq(value: R) {
    println(this.name + " = $value")
}

infix fun <T, R> KProperty1<T, R>.eq(value: KProperty1<T, R>) {
    println(this.name + " = " + value.name)
}

data class Person(val age: Int, val name: String, val surname: String?)

fun main() {
    Person::age eq 1  // Valid. First function
    Person::name eq "Johan"  // Valid. First function
    Person::name eq Person::name  // Valid. Second function
    Person::age eq 1.2f  // Valid, but it shouldn't be. First function
    Person::age eq Person::name  // Valid, but it shouldn't be. First function
    Person::surname eq null  // Invalid, but it should be. Second function, but it should be first
}
```

I am trying create extension functions for the `KProperty1` class with generics, but my generics are not matching as I'd expect. `main()` lists some uses of the two functions, with 3 unexpected results at the end and a description of what I should expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that [`KProperty1<T, out R>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property1/index.html) has an [`out`-projected type parameter `R`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections), so an instance of `KProperty1<Foo, Bar>` can also be used where a `KProperty1<Foo, Baz>` is expected, where `Baz` is a supertype of `Bar`, such as `Any`.

This is exactly what happens when you call `eq` with types that don't quite match: a more common supertype is used so that the call resolves correctly.

For example, this call:

```
Person::age eq 1.2f
```

is effectively equivalent to:

```
Person::age.eq<Person, Any>(1.2f)
```

<sup>You can even transform it to this form automatically be applying *Replace infix call with ordinary call* and then *Add explicit type arguments*.</sup>

So whenever the types don't match exactly, a common supertype is chosen for `R`. Currently, there's no proper way to tell the compiler it should not fall back to the supertype (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596420/how-do-i-constrain-a-kotlin-extension-function-parameter-to-be-the-same-as-the-e/39598190)).

The last call is a side effect of how type inference currently works: it seems like the compiler has to choose one of the overloads before it decides on whether it is compatible for nullability. If you replace `null` with `(null as String?)` it works. Please file an issue for this at [kotl.in/issue](https://kotl.in/issue).

In general, it is preferable not to mix the generic signatures with non-generic ones because of possible generic substitutions that lead to ambiguity. In your case, a substitution `R := KProperty1<T, Foo>` (i.e. using `eq` on a property of this type) would lead to ambiguity.

Also relevant:

- [Kotlin - Generic Type Parameters Not Being Respected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318179/kotlin-generic-type-parameters-not-being-respected/57359580#57359580)

  <sup>(basically the same case, but with a more detailed explanation of how type inference works here)</sup>