# Stopping generics from inferring Any type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, type-inference, typing, parameterized-types

I understand what's going on here, but I don't know the right way to fix it.  Consider the following code:

```
data class MyClass<T>(val a: T, val b: T)

val myVal = MyClass(1,2)
val myVal2 = MyClass(1,"b")
```

`myVal1` is inferred to a type of `MyClass<Int>`.  This is what I want.  But `myVal2` is inferred to a `MyClass<Any>`.

I understand that it's because `Any` is a supertype of an `Int` and a `String`, but what I really want is a compiler error to get raised because `1` and `"b"` are not matching types.

I would like to accomplish this with type inference, rather than explicitly declaring `MyClass<Int>`.

I've looked at several [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717977/generic-extensions-of-kproperty1-in-kotlin/52720842#52720842) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318179/kotlin-generic-type-parameters-not-being-respected/57359580#57359580), but I they say that it's because the `KProperty` object uses an `out T` declaration.  I don't have that issue here.

**Motivation**

I want this to build a class for defining comparison relationships, such as "equals", "greater than", etc.  In my case I actually do want to use a `KProperty`.  For example,

`data class equalTo(val prop: KProperty<*,T>, val compareTo: T)`.

Basically, the compiler should stop you if you try to define:

```
val myCompare = equalTo(MyClass::myStringProperty, 123)
```

Since it is nonsensical to ask if a `String` property is equal to an `Int`.  There might be a better way to implement this concept. If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to ensure they are the exact same subtype at the compiler level. This would also be an ambiguous concept. Two classes from different class hierarchies could be the exact same type if they implement the same interface.

But you should only care if the two of them have the same specific functions/properties you intend to call on them. In this case, you described wanting to compare their sizes. So what you actually need is for both values to be comparable by the same type, and you can bound the type as `Comparable<T>`.

```
data class MyClass<T: Comparable<T>>(val a: T, val b: T)
```

You could also use this with a property, sort of how you described, although a KProperty has only one generic type.

```
data class MyClass<T: Comparable<T>>(val prop: KProperty<T>, val b: T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

In your example, an `Int` [is an](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a#Liskov_substitution_principle) instance of `Any`.  It's actually an instance of a subclass, but a subclass can do everything its base class can do, and is in all respects an instance of the base class; that's the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in action.

A `String` is also an `Any` in the same way.

So you have two `Any`s, and everything works out.  Even if you were to do something clever with variance or type bounds, I think it would still be able to infer a suitable supertype in this way.

It might help if you could explain what you're trying to achieve by this, and why the `Any` inference isn't acceptable to you.  Would you accept a call with, say, an `ArrayList` and a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` (which have no common ancestor other than `Any`/`Object`, though they do implement some common interfaces)?  Or `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` (which both extend `AbstractList`)?  What if `listOf()` were enhanced in future to return specialised classes for very small lists (like Scala does), so that `listOf(1)` returned a different class from `listOf(1, 2)` — would those be acceptable?  If not, why not?

Comment: I just edited my question to explain my motivation.  If there's a better way to implement such a concept, I'm open to suggestions.